# Change directory of FileList when referencing it

Tags: ant, build, directory, copy, filelist

I want to change the base directory of a `FileList` when referencing it later in my buildfile.

I define the following `FileList`:

```
<filelist dir="./dev" id="sourceFiles">
    <file name="files/file.php" />
    <file name="files/class.php" />
    <file name="files/functions.php" />
</filelist>
```

And my targets are the following

```
<target name="fetch">
    <copy todir="./src/files">
        <filelist refid="sourceFiles" />
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="build" depends="fetch">
    <replaceregexp match="(\d+.\d+.\d+)(.\d+)?" replace="\1.${build.number}">
        <filelist refid="sourceFiles" />
    </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

So, when using the `replaceregexp` task, it will use the files located in `./dev` - but I want the task to replace in the files copied earlier that are now located in `./src`.

Of course, I could copy the file list and use another `dir`, but I'd very much like to only hold the list of files once in my buildfile.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: patternset(http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/patternset.html)  may help you to create multiple fileset with different 'top directory'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a mapper within the copy command as follows:

```
<project name="demo" default="copy">

    <property name="build.number" value="1.0.1"/>

    <target name="copy">
        <copy todir="build">
            <fileset dir="src"/>
            <regexpmapper from="^(.*)\.txt$" to="\1.${build.number}"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Here's my test files

```
|-- build
|   `-- files
|       |-- one
|       |   |-- file1.1.0.1
|       |   `-- file2.1.0.1
|       `-- two
|           `-- file3.1.0.1
|-- build.xml
`-- src
    `-- files
        |-- one
        |   |-- file1.txt
        |   `-- file2.txt
        `-- two
            `-- file3.txt
```