# Apache Ant create new fileset from existing fileset with filenames renamed

Tags: ant, fileset

I have the following fileset in my Apache Ant build file (BuildFilesetXML.xml):

```
<fileset id="XMLFileset" dir="mydir/myxml"> 
    <include name="**/1.xml"/>
    <include name="**/2.xml"/>
</fileset>
```

I want to create dynamically in a different build file (BuildFilesetLog.xml) (do not know the contents of "XMLFileset" in my 2nd build file) a new fileset named "LOGFileset" that will have the same contents of "XMLFileset" but with names renamed to .log. So, in runtime it will have the same structure as the following fileset:

```
<fileset id="LOGFileset">   
    <include name="**/1.log"/>
    <include name="**/2.log"/>
</fileset>
```

Can this be done in Ant?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, but some tasks support [mappers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html). For an example see the following answer:

- [Change directory of FileList when referencing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363383/change-directory-of-filelist-when-referencing-it/9368261#9368261)